# How to refresh a Grid class in wxpython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I am currently creating a program that configures IP connections, when I stumbled upon a problem in regards to the refreshing of the data in the Grid, for I have made a Grid class that contained SQL queries that execute once that class is loaded. Said Refresh function has to be done within the Remove, or Modify button.

I have tried using ForceRefresh on the grid class, clearing the data then refreshing, and opening and closing the window altogether. 2 of which didn't work, and the last one just won't load the new data.

```
class MainTable(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)
#Insert functions and SQL queries...

class dspdtb(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None, style = wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
#More stuff below...


        btn2 = BP.ButtonInfo(titleBar, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap("button5 a.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
        titleBar.AddButton(btn2)
        btn2.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap("button5 b.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG), status="Pressed")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Removal, btn2)

#Still more stuff below...

        grid = MainTable(panel)
        vSizer.Add(titleBar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        vSizer.Add((20, 20))
        vSizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTRE, 50)
        titleBar.DoLayout()
        vSizer.Layout()
        #toolbar end
        self.Show()
        self.Maximize(True)

#Insert other functions here...

    def Removal(self, event):
        global l_a
        t = len(l_a)
        n = 0
        chk = wx.MessageBox('Do you wanna delete the selected items?', 'Confirm Deletion', wx.YES_NO)
        if chk==2:
            while(n<t):
                sasa = l_a[n]
                print (sasa)
                try: 
                    mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM ip_config WHERE id=%s;", (sasa,))
                except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
                mydb.commit()
                n+=1
            wx.MessageBox('Rows now deleted, the table will now reload.', 'Deletion Completed', wx.OK)
        l_a=[]
        MainTable.ForceRefresh()
```

I needed the Program to Refresh either the dspdtb class or the Grid class to refresh the data. But when I have executed the program, this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Internal_IT\Desktop\IP automation\wxt.py", line 332, in Removal
    MainTable.ForceRefresh()
TypeError: Grid.ForceRefresh(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'Grid'
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, the problem should be that you are creating a MainTable object in your class.

```
grid = MainTable(panel)
```

Then in the Removal method you want to call the ForceRefresh method form the MainTable class, like so.

```
MainTable.ForceRefresh()
```

Probably you should call this method on the MainTable object itself, like this.

```
self.grid.ForceRefresh()
```

Before you do this, don't forget to create the grid as a instance variable with self, like this.

```
self.grid = MainTable(panel)
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Seems like it didn't work... The refresh didn't take into effect after I have made the removal function.